# Program Running in a Loop

Tags: c++

Im trying to figure out why the program runs in a loop.  I just can't see how it starts the loop. would like to give you more info but just run the code and do everything right and the program just starts back over but not at the beginning.  It will start from when I am selecting the payment option.
here is the code and the code is c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int option, pause, payment, selection, zipcode, error, pin, quantity_chips, quantity_milk, quantity_cola,
    quantity_coffee, quantity_pennies, quantity_nickels, quantity_dimes, quantity_quarters, quantity_dollars,
    quantity_fives, quantity_tens, quantity_twenties, quantity_total;
float chips, milk, cola, coffee, total, tax, final_cost, pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters,
    dollars, fives, tens, twenties, cash_total, owed, change;

void checkout(), debitcard (), creditcard (), cash (), receipt ();

void menu ()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Kenjin Xer0's Item Pooper.\n"
            << "10 or less items.\n";
    do
    {
        quantity_total = (quantity_chips) + (quantity_milk) + (quantity_cola) + (quantity_coffee);
        cout << "Select from our menu:                  Selected\n"
            << "\t1. Potato Chip.....$1.50......" << quantity_chips << "\n"
            << "\t2. 2% Milk.........$2.00......" << quantity_milk << "\n"
            << "\t3. Off Brand Cola..$1.00......" << quantity_cola << "\n"
            << "\t4. Dark Coffee.....$2.50......" << quantity_coffee << "\n"
            << "\t5. Check out            Total:" << quantity_total << "\n";
        cout << "Enter your option: ";
        cin >> option;
        if (option == 1)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_chips;
            chips = (1.5 * quantity_chips);
        }
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_milk;
            milk = (2 * quantity_milk);
        }
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_cola;
            cola = (1 * quantity_cola); 
        }
        else if (option == 4)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";    
            cin >> quantity_coffee;   
            coffee = (2.5 * quantity_coffee);  
        }   
        else if (option == 5)
        {
            if (total > 10)
            {
                cout << "Problem! 10 or less line, Man!\n";
                option = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                checkout();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid option.\n";
        } 
    } 
    while (option !=5);
}

void checkout ()
{   
    do
    {
        cout << "Select payment option (1:Debit 2:Credit 3:Cash): ";
        cin >> payment;
        if (payment == 1) 
        {
            debitcard ();
        }
        else if (payment == 2)  
        {
            creditcard ();      
        } 
        else if (payment == 3)
        {
            cash ();
        }
        else 
        {  
            cout << "Weird Choice, try again.\n";
        }
    }
    while (payment != 1||2||3);
}

void debitcard ()
{
    error = 3;
    do
    {
        error--;
        cout << "Enter PIN:\n"; 
        cin >> pin;
        if (error == 0)
        {
            cout << "We are sorry but does this card acually belong to you.\n"
                << "Now Leave.\n";
            break;
        }
        else if (pin != 0000) 
        {
             cout << "Wrong. Try Again\n"
                 << "You now have " << error << " more tries\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            receipt();
        }
    }
    while (pin != 0000);
}

void creditcard ()
{
    error = 3;
    do
    {
        error--;
        cout << "Enter Zip:\n"; 
        cin >> zipcode;
        if (error == 0)
        {
            cout << "We are sorry but does this card acually belong to you.\n"
                << "Now Leave.\n";
            break;
        }
        else if (zipcode != 77523) 
        {
             cout << "Wrong. Try Again\n"
                 << "You now have " << error << " more tries\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            receipt();
        }
    }
    while (zipcode != 77523);
}

void cash ()
{
    total = (chips) + (milk) + (cola) + (coffee);
    tax = (total * .10);
    final_cost = tax + total;
    cout << "You owe $"<< final_cost <<".\n";
    do
    {
        cash_total = (pennies) + (nickels) + (dimes) + (quarters) + (dollars) + (fives) + (tens) + (twenties);
        owed = final_cost - cash_total;
        cout << "Select the Amount:\n"
            << "\t1. Penny................$0.01......" << quantity_pennies << "\n"
            << "\t2. Nickel...............$0.05......" << quantity_nickels << "\n"
            << "\t3. Dime.................$0.10......" << quantity_dimes << "\n"
            << "\t4. Quarter..............$0.25......" << quantity_quarters << "\n"
            << "\t5. One Dollar Bill......$1.00......" << quantity_dollars << "\n"
            << "\t6. Five Dollars Bill....$5.00......" << quantity_fives << "\n"
            << "\t7. Ten Dollar Bill......$10.00....." << quantity_tens << "\n"
            << "\t8. Twenty Dollar Bill...$20.00....." << quantity_twenties << "\n"
            << "\t9. Cash Out\n"
            << "Cash you Have: $" << cash_total << "           Still owe: $" << owed << "\n";
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
        if (selection == 1) 
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_pennies;
            pennies = (0.01 * quantity_pennies); 
        }
        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_nickels;
            nickels = (0.05 * quantity_nickels); 
        }
        else if (selection == 3)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_dimes;
            dimes = (0.10 * quantity_dimes); 
        }
        else if (selection == 4)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_quarters;
            quarters = (0.25 * quantity_quarters); 
        }
        else if (selection == 5)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_dollars;
            dollars = (1.00 * quantity_dollars); 
        }
        else if (selection == 6)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_fives;
            fives = (5.00 * quantity_fives); 
        }
        else if (selection == 7)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_tens;
            tens = (10.00 * quantity_tens); 
        }
        else if (selection == 8)
        {
            cout << "Quantity: ";
            cin >> quantity_twenties;
            twenties = (20.00 * quantity_twenties); 
        }
        else if (selection == 9)
        {
            receipt ();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid option.\n";
        }
    }
    while (selection != 9);
}

void receipt ()
{
    total = (chips) + (milk) + (cola) + (coffee);
    tax = (total * .10);
    final_cost = tax + total;
    change = owed * -1;
    cout << "Receipt Take:\n"; 
    if (quantity_chips > 0)
    {  
        cout << "Potato Chips: $1.50 x " << quantity_chips << " = $" << chips << endl; 
    }   
    if (quantity_milk > 0)  
    {        
        cout << "2% Milk: $2.00 x " << quantity_milk << " = $" << milk << endl;
    }
    if (quantity_cola > 0) 
    { 
        cout << "Off Brand Cola: 1.00 x " << quantity_cola << " = $" << cola << endl; 
    }   
    if (quantity_coffee > 0) 
    { 
        cout << "Dark Coffee: $2.50 x " << quantity_coffee << " = $" << coffee << endl;  
    }  
    cout << "Tax (10.0%): $" << tax << endl; 
    cout << "Total: $" << final_cost << endl;
    cout << "Change Returned: $" << change << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    menu ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific, provide output. Most of us are not going to simply compile your code and run it. Even if someone did, there is no guarantee that they would get the same results.

Comment: `while (payment != 1||2||3);`  Unfortunately, C++ doesn't understand English vernacular.  This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Is the declaration of the functions valid syntax (or is it valid function declaration syntax)?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `switch` statement?

Comment: When adding variables, the parenthesis is not necessary and does not improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop that you have in `checkout()` is incorrect.  You have:

```
while (payment != 1||2||3);
```

Which is not how you do mutiple or's.  You would need to write it as

```
while (payment != 1 || payment != 2 || payment != 3);
```

Comment: I recommend using parenthesis to group things.  I believe it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

in ur checkout function
replace

```
while (payment != 1||2||3)
```

by

```
while (payment != 1 && payment != 2 && payment != 3)
```

Comment: Please review your logical operators.  Nathan Oliver uses `||`, but you use `&&`.  Which is it?

Comment: logically , we quit the checkout function when payment is different of the 3 value (1 && 2 && 3), not (1 or 2 or 3)

Comment: sorry for my beloved english

Answer (score 0):

To remove the confusing set of conditions that you've done to exit the do-while loop in the `checkout` function, this can be done instead:

```
void checkout ()
{   
    bool choice_made;
    do
    {
        choice_made = true;

        cout << "Select payment option (1:Debit 2:Credit 3:Cash): ";
        cin >> payment;
        if (payment == 1) 
        {
            debitcard ();
        }
        else if (payment == 2)  
        {
            creditcard ();      
        } 
        else if (payment == 3)
        {
            cash ();
        }
        else 
        {  
            cout << "Weird Choice, try again.\n";
            choice_made = false;
        }
    }
    while (!choice_made);  
}
```

You only exit the loop until a valid choice is made.  A simple boolean is all you need to control the logic.

As to your attempt, this line:

```
while (payment != 1||2||3)
```

applies the logical `or` to the values of 1, 2, and 3.  The result is always `true`, which is 1.  So what it all boils down to is

```
while (payment != 1)
```